hostpad with pyrad as test radius server not asking for credentials when connecting to created access point
I'm trying to create an access point with hostpad and pyrad that uses radius authentification on linux, I was able to create the access point with hostpad using the following configuration
interface=wlan1
driver=nl80211
ssid=Radius
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

# WPA2-Enterprise Configuration
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
wpa_pairwise=CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

# RADIUS server configuration
auth_server_addr=127.0.0.1
auth_server_port=1812
auth_server_shared_secret=secret123

and it will show up on my windows machine as an access point, but when trying to connect to the ap, instead of asking for radius credentials, it keeps saying "Checking network requirements" for a while until it just gives up and says "Can't connecct to this network".
The output of hostpad gives me the following
wlan1: RADIUS Authentication server 127.0.0.1:1812
wlan1: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
wlan1: AP-ENABLED
wlan1: STA {mac address here} IEEE 802.11: authenticated
wlan1: STA {mac address here} IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
wlan1: STA {mac address here} IEEE 802.11: authenticated
wlan1: STA {mac address here} IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
wlan1: STA {mac address here} IEEE 802.11: authenticated
wlan1: STA {mac address here} IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
wlan1: STA {mac address here} IEEE 802.11: authenticated
wlan1: STA {mac address here} IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
wlan1: STA {mac address here} IEEE 802.11: authenticated
wlan1: STA {mac address here} IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
wlan1: STA {mac address here} IEEE 802.11: authenticated
wlan1: STA {mac address here} IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)

I've tried different versions for the radius auth server in python, the current one I'm using is
import StringIO
import os
import sys
import signal
from pyrad import dictionary, packet, server

DICTIONARY = """
ATTRIBUTE\tUser-Name\t1\tstring
ATTRIBUTE\tUser-Password\t2\toctets
ATTRIBUTE\tNAS-Identifier\t32\tstring
"""

class TestServer(server.Server):
    def _HandleAuthPacket(self, pkt):
        server.Server._HandleAuthPacket(self, pkt)

        passwd = []
        print('received auth packet')

        for key in pkt.keys():
            if key == "User-Password":
                passwd = map(pkt.PwDecrypt, pkt[key])

        reply = self.CreateReplyPacket(pkt)
        if passwd == ['accept']:
            reply.code = packet.AccessAccept
        else:
            reply.code = packet.AccessReject
        self.SendReplyPacket(pkt.fd, reply)

srv = TestServer(addresses=["localhost"],
                 hosts={"127.0.0.1":
                        server.RemoteHost("127.0.0.1", "secret123", "localhost")},
                 dict=dictionary.Dictionary(StringIO.StringIO(DICTIONARY)))

srv.Run()


but it seems like it doesn't even get to the point where it prints that it has received an auth packet.
